# Retrieve metadata of EmailTemplate HTML and Text version

Tags: soap-api, email-template, metadata-api, metadata

I'm trying to fetch an EmailTemplate using metadata api, file-based `retreive()` call. The request is being made using SOAP api to make the retrieve request through javascript.

I'm getting only the email HTML version (screenshot attached), and not the text version.

Following is my code:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve_request.htm

```
    var req, result;
    req = new sforce.RetrieveRequest();
    req.apiVersion = "29.0";
    req.singlePackage = false;
    req.unpackaged = {
        types: [{name: "EmailTemplate", members:["Sample_Emails/Email_Template_1"]}]
    };
    sforce.metadata.retrieve(req, function (result) {

        console.log(result);

        var emailZip = new JSZip();
        emailZip.loadAsync(result.zipFile)
            .then(function(zip){
                saveAs(blob, "emailTemplate.zip");
            });          
    });
```

Request - Package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Sample_Emails/Email_Template_1</members>
        <name>EmailTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <version>29.0</version>
</Package>
```

Is there any modification do I've to make to the package.xml request file structure to retrieve the full EmailTemplate information?

[image]

Comment: The Text Version is in the "email-meta.xml" not in the ".email". Did you check there ?

Comment: @CloudNinja You're right, it should be in this file but it is missing those details:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmailTemplate xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <available>true</available>
    <description>Sample Email Template 1</description>
    <encodingKey>UTF-8</encodingKey>
    <name>Email Template 1</name>
    <style>none</style>
    <type>custom</type>
</EmailTemplate>`

Comment: Are you sure your email template type is html or custom ?

Comment: @CloudNinja It is of type custom.